# Remove shadow on Highstock

Tags: javascript, web-applications, charts, highcharts

I'm using Highstock library, and I want to delete [image: this shadow] from my chart, does anyone know?
Thanks.

Comment: Please, show us your code.

Comment: if its the shadow you want gone my answer is correct, if you want to make the actual line then @HalvorStrand 's answer below is correct.
its hard to tell form your pic what you want exactly, shadow or line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is the `lineWidth` of the axis ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.lineWidth)). Set it to `0` (which is also the default):

```
yAxis: [{
    // ...
    lineWidth: 0
}]
```

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jt6pqbfr/) of two y-axis, one with `lineWidth` set to `0` and one set to `2`.

Comment: guess it wasnt the shadow after all!

Answer (score 1):

In your chart object set shadow to false:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: false
    },
```

**Example fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/L3fw3tr4/

play with the code and press run at the top.